# Navigation item only clickable under the item?

Tags: php, html, css

First of all I know this question is confusing, I couldn't think of any other way to explain it. Basically, I made a test login system on my website ad for some reason, the navigation bar works fine when you hover over it on the Home page, but on the login and register page, you have to find a certain spot under the item on the navigation bar to be able to hover over it or click it. For some reason this isn't happening on the Home page, but only those two pages.

Website: http://www.abyssallogin.hol.es/

**Index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require 'login/database.php';

    if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
        $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,username,password FROM users WHERE id = :id');

        $records->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user_id']);

        $records->execute();

        $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $user = NULL;

        if( count($results) > 0){
            $user = $results;
        }
    }
?>

<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Login Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if( !empty($user) ): ?>

            <nav class="navigation">
                <div class="navigation-logo">Website</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Deposit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Withdraw</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Free Coins</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Support</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form id="button" action='login/logout' method='POST'><button class="btn" name='logout' type='submit'>Logout</button></form>
            </nav>
            <span class="login-message">You are now logged in.</span>

        <? else: ?>

            <nav class="navigation">
                <div class="navigation-logo">Website</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index" class="navigation-item">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Deposit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Withdraw</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Free Coins</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Support</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form id="button" action='login/login' method='POST'><button class="btn" name='login' type='submit'>Login</button></form>
            </nav>
            <span class="login-message">You are not currently logged in.</span>

        <? endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
        header("Location: /");
    }

    require 'database.php';

    $message = '';

    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):
        $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,username,password FROM users WHERE username = :username');

        $records->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);

        $records->execute();

        $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password']) ){
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results['id'];
            header("Location: /");
        } else {
            $message = 'Incorrect username or password.';
        }
    endif;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Login Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/login.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <div class="navigation-logo">Website</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../index" class="navigation-item">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Deposit</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Withdraw</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Free Coins</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Support</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form id="button" action='login' method='POST'><button class="btn" name='login' type='submit'>Login</button></form>
        </nav>
        <form action="login" method="POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
            <span class="register-text">Don't have an account? <a href="register">Register Here</a></span>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){
        header("Location: /");
    }

    require 'database.php';

    if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);

        $hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $hash);

        if( $stmt->execute() ):
            $message = '';
            header("Location: login");
        else:
            $message = '';
        endif;

    endif;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Login Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/register.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <div class="navigation-logo">Website</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../index" class="navigation-item">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Deposit</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Withdraw</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Free Coins</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navigation-item">Support</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form id="button" action='login' method='POST'><button class="btn" name='login' type='submit'>Login</button></form>
        </nav>
        <form action="register" method="POST">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm_password">
            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
            <span class="register-text">Already have an account? <a href="login">Login Here</a></span>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Index.css**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

.navigation > .navigation-logo {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 15px 30px;
}

.navigation > ul {
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 190px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation > ul > li {
    float: left;
}

.navigation > ul > li > .navigation-item {
    height: 40px;
    margin-left:15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navigation > ul > li > .navigation-item:before {
    left: 0px;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(215, 85, 80);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navigation > ul > li > .navigation-item:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

.navigation > ul > li > .navigation-item:hover {
    color: rgb(215, 85, 80);
}

#button {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}

.btn {
    float: right;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding: 5px 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.btn:hover {
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.login-message {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

**Login.css**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

.navigation > .navigation-logo {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 15px 30px;
}

.navigation > ul {
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 190px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation > ul > li {
    float: left;
}

.navigation > ul > li > .navigation-item {
    height: 40px;
    margin-left:15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navigation > ul > li > .navigation-item:before {
    left: 0px;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(215, 85, 80);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navigation > ul > li > .navigation-item:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

.navigation > ul > li > .navigation-item:hover {
    color: rgb(215, 85, 80);
}

#button {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}

.btn {
    float: right;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding: 5px 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.btn:hover {
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

form {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 40%;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    border: 2px solid rgb(40, 40, 40);
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    outline: 2px solid rgb(40, 40, 40);
    background: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 320px;
    border: 0px;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
    outline: 2px solid rgb(40, 40, 40);
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

.register-text {
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
}

.register-text a {
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}
```

**Register.css**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

.navigation > .navigation-logo {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 15px 30px;
}

.navigation > ul {
    margin: 0px;
    float: right;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 190px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation > ul > li {
    float: left;
}

.navigation > ul > li > .navigation-item {
    height: 40px;
    margin-left:15px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navigation > ul > li > .navigation-item:before {
    left: 0px;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(215, 85, 80);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navigation > ul > li > .navigation-item:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

.navigation > ul > li > .navigation-item:hover {
    color: rgb(215, 85, 80);
}

#button {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}

.btn {
    float: right;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding: 5px 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.btn:hover {
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

form {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 40%;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    border: 2px solid rgb(40, 40, 40);
    margin: 10px auto;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    outline: 2px solid rgb(40, 40, 40);
    background: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 320px;
    border: 0px;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
    outline: 2px solid rgb(40, 40, 40);
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}

.register-text {
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
}

.register-text a {
    color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check DOCTYPE, in register you have `<!DOCTYPE html>`, in index `<DOCTYPE html>`.
2. Quotes are interchangeably, but it's good practice to use one type. `"` or `'`, not both of them.
3. I've replaced register.css content by index.css content and navbar's working good again. As I see – problem's in register.css with that:

   ```
   form {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   top: 40%;
   }
   ```

   And that point is about that, real problem.

Using `form` instead of class, for example, you're changing two(sic!) forms. Firstly that which you want, and secondly that one in `<nav class="navigation">`! Just use class while doing that and everything will be good ;)

For example, register.css:

```
    .registerForm {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 40%;
    }
```

And register html:

```
    <form class="registerForm" action="http://www.abyssallogin.hol.es/login/register" method="POST">
```

4. Everything you should do like that. Using html tags in css is not so good idea. Use id, class, and keep it simple. index.css and register.css are almost the same. You can import more css files than one – use that functionality! Only then css have really sense ;)

Comment: Ok so that seemed to work but there is still one problem. Now on my login page, the form is all the way at the top. You can go to the same link and check it out.

Comment: Oh come on... don't you even read code you've wrote? You have in html ``clas=``, not ``class=``...

Comment: Omfg sorry man lol I didn't even see that. Thanks for the help.